# Not able to build F# project in Azure Pipeline

Tags: f#, azure-devops, sqlclient

I have an `f#` project in dotnet core 2.2 with following dependencies.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Expecto" Version="8.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.5" />
```

I can build and run this locally without any problem.
But when trying to build this on azure pipeline I get the following error.

`error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlCommandProvider' reported an error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.`

I tryed adding `System.Data.SqlClient` packages. But still not working.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Expecto" Version="8.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLProvider" Version="1.1.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
```

When I try to add `System.Data.SqlClient` Version="4.4.0" i get following error locally

`Detected package downgrade: System.Data.SqlClient from 4.5.1 to 4.4.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 ElbBazarApiComponentTest -> FSharp.Data.SqlClient 2.0.6 -> System.Data.SqlClient (>= 4.5.1) 
 ElbBazarApiComponentTest -> System.Data.SqlClient (>= 4.4.0)   ElbBazarApiComponentTest    F:\ElbBazar\ElbBazarApi\ElbBazarApiComponentTest\ElbBazarApiComponentTest.fsproj`

I do not know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not able to build F# project in Azure Pipeline

According to the error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.
```

It state that Could not **load** file or assembly rather than Could not **found** file or assembly.

Besides, when we check the nuget package [FSharp.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/2.0.5), which have dependencies:

[image]

So, the reason for that error is not that we have lost references `System.Data.SqlClient`, just we could not load it.

AFAIK, there is [issue on the github](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/626) about it, you could check if the workaround work for you, use MSBuild instead of dotnet build to build this project.

Hope this helps.